# Problema con un tema de Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wamp

Veran, estoy probando un tema de Wordpress llamado Scholarship en WAMP.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es su página de inicio, cuando pongo que muestre las últimas entradas.
La historia es que tengo una página que quiero que sea mi página principal, llamada "Bienvenido a Autismo Cádiz".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero cuando hago que esta sea la página principal, me topo con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El menú de Inicio tapa parte de la página principal.
¿Como soluciono esto para que el menú principal no tape la página de inicio?

Este error no me sucede si la página no es la de inicio, ni si uso de página de inicio la página por defecto que lista las últimas noticias, por lo que todo esto me extraña.

Comment: No quieres que lo tape, pero ¿dónde debe quedar?. Necesitaremos ver HTML y estilos.

Comment: @Sal Si te fijas, incluso parte del widget de las redes sociales es tapado. La cosa es que se tendria que ver igual que la 2ª imagen, en la cual el menú no tapa nada.

Answer (score 1):

El menú te está tapando parte del contenido principal de la página ya que al no caber a lo ancho en su totalidad, parte del mismo se está mostrando en una segunda fila.

Sin saber los estilos con los que se está mostrando ese menú, lo más probable es que el propio menú esté posicionado absolutamente y el contenido principal espere que el menú tenga un alto de X valor, el que tiene originalmente cuando los ítems del menú se muestren todos en una única línea, hecho que no sucede cuando éste rompe en dos líneas para mostrar todos sus ítems.

O acortas el ancho que ocupan los ítems del menú según el ancho del dispositivo o usas javascript para igualar la altura del menú con la distancia que hay desde el inicio del contendido principal de la página hasta la parte superior de la pantalla.

Comment: Bueno, he intentado si podia pasar el menú a estatico, pero no tuve suerte. Mañana vuelvo a probar a ver si eso lo arregla.